# References to a Convex Analysis result.

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, projection

I am writing an article for future publication. Due to the limit of pages that the publication delimits for your published articles I do not have space to include the demonstration of several secondary results. One of these secondary results is the result below that I found only in a single references.

> Let $K$ a convex and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
>
> 1. for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there is one, and only one, $x_K\in K$ such that $\|x-x_K\|\leq \| x-c\|$ for all $c\in K$;
> 2. the map $\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\mapsto x_K\in K$ is uniformly continuous and for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\|x_K-y_K\|\leq \|x-y\|$.

But there are two problems with this reference.

- First, the reference is a somewhat inaccessible book, because it is a book written in Portuguese and the last edition is from 1976. That is, the book is no longer editable
- Second, the result is in the pre-hilbertian space context where $ K $ has the property of complete rather than the property of being compact.

> **My question.** Is there any reference to the above result that is accessible and restricted to finite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: enough to assume $K$ closed (in $\mathbb{R}^n$). why not say "the result is standard and proof is omitted"  as a quick fix?

Comment: See, e.g., Bauschke and Combettes's *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces*, 2nd edition, Springer, Theorem 3.16 and Proposition 4.16.